# Loading of script tag is slower in Chrome than Firefox

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, parsing, firefox

I want to load large amounts of data from a local file in an html application.

At the moment my strategy is to keep the data as javascript arrays in separate .js files and load them by dynamically adding  elements to the header of the page, like so:

```
const head = document.getElementsByTagName['head'][0]
const js = document.createElement('script')
js.async = true
js.src = "localDataFile.js"
head.appendChild(js)
```

The contents of localDataFile.js look like the following, where dataString contains the data encoded as a base64 string.

```
const base64DataString = "..."
globalFunction(base64DataString)
```

An example .js file I am using has a size of 300 MiB.
This file takes ~40 seconds to load in Chrome, and ~16 seconds in Firefox, **current** versions.

**My question:**
Is there any way to speed up parsing of this javascript file for Chrome, or both?
More generally, are there any better strategies in getting the data to the html application without using a web server?

Comment: why are you using such old versions of browsers? what's the speed in the **current** versions?

Comment: A more usual way to retreive data would be to use JSON or XML data files (as long as you don't need to get functions from your data, you cannot have functions in JSON, it doesn't seem to be in the standard for XML either). I have no idea though about performances, it's parsing and executing JavaScript versus parsing JSON, but my intuition tells me the latter would be quicker

Comment: NOTE: your data seems to be a single string, if you want to try with JSON, all you need to do is wrap your string with double quotes `"` in a `.json` file and it should work. If you have multiple ones your best solution will be to use an object with keys pointing to your strings

Comment: @JaromandaX Current versions give similar results.

Comment: when you say it takes 16/40 seconds to load, where is this timing from? does it include the time `globalFunction` takes to run? or is it just the time taken to load/parse the huge javascript?

Comment: This question is too vague. You are going to have to explain why you are loading your "data" the way you are. Why is it so large? Do you need all of it after you load it? Why not use a more "normal" approach (json/ajax/xml)?